# Upload image with Alamofire with MultiFormData

Tags: ios, swift, image-uploading, alamofire, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload image with server.
In Android, it work perfect with this code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
String strPath = "D:\\Personal\\Projects\\Resources\\Images\\ic_flash_on.png";
Path path = Paths.get(strPath);
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);

map.add("id", 2);
map.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(bytes) {
  @Override
  public String getFilename() {
    return "ic_flash_on.png";
  }
});

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
headers.add("Authorization", request.getHeader("Authorization"));

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> imageEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, headers);
ResponseEntity<Photo> result = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/api/photos/upload", HttpMethod.POST,
    imageEntity, Photo.class);
return result;
```

In iOS, I am using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) with code:

```
let url = HOST + "api/photos/upload"

    let accessToken = KeychainHelper.getStringForKey(KeychainConstaint.kAccessTokenKey) ?? ""
    let headers = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer \(accessToken)",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    ]

    Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        url,
        headers: headers,
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            var id = 10000
            let idData = NSData(bytes: &id, length: sizeof(Int))
            //multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: photo.data, name: "file")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: idData, name: "id")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: photo.data, name: "file", fileName: ".jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        },
        encodingMemoryThreshold: Manager.MultipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold) { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
    }
```

And it fail with reason: "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present"

Did I missing anything? :(

Comment: I hear your struggle, I had what looks like a similar problem today. In my case, it had to do with the parameter "withName" and "fileName" in the multipartFormData.append() call.
I would suggest, if you have control of the Spring back end, to add a "Filter" class with a breakpoint where you can investigate both the 'good' and 'bad' requests to see exactly what's different (it will reach the breakpoint before failing with that error message).

Comment: Hi. I found that fileName: should not format like this ".jpg". 
I was conflict the 'name' parameter and 'fileName' in that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
let url = HOST + "api/photos/upload"

let accessToken = KeychainHelper.getStringForKey(KeychainConstaint.kAccessTokenKey) ?? ""
let headers = [
    "Authorization": "Bearer \(accessToken)",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
]

var parameters = [String:AnyObject]()

var id = 10000
let idData = NSData(bytes: &id, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)

parameters = ["id":idData as AnyObject]

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

    multipartFormData.append(photo.data , withName: "image" , fileName: ".jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    // + sessionid + "/" + mobile
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
    }

},to: url, method: .post, headers: nil ,
  encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    switch encodingResult {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.response { [weak self] response in
            guard self != nil else {
                return
            }
            debugPrint(response)
        }
    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print("error:\(encodingError)")
    }


})
```